# C# Iterate Through CheckBoxList Insert Selected Items Into SQL Columns

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a CheckBoxList that displays around 20 options.  I would like to iterate through and take the selected items from the list and insert them into 5 different columns in a database.

I disable the checkboxlist after 5 items are selected so I am good there.  I just need to know how to iterate through and insert the selected items.

How would I get this accomplished?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can get the checked checkboxes like this

```
var checkedCheckBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                            .Where(c => c.Checked);
```

replace `this` with a container that has the checkboxes if it's not the outer most container such as a Form.

and then you can loop thru items in checkedCheckBoxes and formulate your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<CheckBox>()
                   .Where(s => s.Checked)
                   .Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ***list of checkboxes*** or [**`CheckedListBox`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) control?

As answers have been provided for first one already, take a look at [`CheckedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkedindices.aspx) or [`CheckedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx) properties of `CheckedListBox` control in case that's what you use.

Quick example:

```
// Cast<string>() should be replaced by whatever data type you use
var checkedItems = checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Cast<string>();
foreach (var item in checkedItems)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
```